# How do you view POST information from a JQuery AJAX post request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using PhoneGap and making a JQuery AJAX post from JavaScript. I'd like to be able to view the actual POST request to PHP so that I can confirm that it is being sent correctly. Does anyone here know how to do that? My pseudocode is attached.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) {
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressFunc, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            //Ajax events
            success: completeHandler = function(data) {
                //...
            },
            data: { ... },
            dataType: "json",
            //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            error: function(e) {
               //...
            }
        });
```

Comment: why not view it in php? var_dump($_POST) or error_log(var_export($_POST), true).

Comment: 1. This is not pseudocode, 2. When you make a POST request you need to treat it as a POST request. Do it on the server side, client side code is ok.

Comment: You can easily write all post requests to a log. do a search for fopen and fwrite

Comment: The ? says "I'd like to be able to view the actual POST request to PHP so that I can confirm that it is being sent correctly". PHP should validate the "actual POST" and that provides opportunity to see the request. If you don't have access, then wrap it and send to JS console. A  hackish alternative -> drop it in an alert(). Other methods avail, these are the fast ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the request in Chrome Developer Tools. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> and then click the Network tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to **confirm** that the request is being made, use the <kbd>F12</kbd> button and go to the Network tab to check for the request details.

If it is invoking, it would be there, otherwise you won't get it in the list.

Secondly, you will be able to see the Request headers and the Response headers that would be sent. If there is an error, you'll see that error too. Go ahead, try it. Your code is ok. And it would make a `POST` request to the server.

Comment: I don't know PhoneGap very well, but the JS may be on the PG side and the post is not a product of the browser (client side). I could be wrong, but if this is the case the browser network tools will not pick up on the outgoing request as PG is making it (PG app to external server/PHP).

Comment: Every network request is captured in the Networks tab of the Browser. If there is an external app, it must be an app outside from the browser. If its making a request from the browser. It would be captured! @datamafia ..

Comment: There is an element called "Phone Gap Build" that is a cloud service acting as the intermediary "compiler" for JS/CSS/HTML into the application. PG uses a foreign function interface to create hybrid application that are wrapped using JS and much additional PG magic. Via http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonegap "Adobe's PhoneGap Build service allows programmers to upload HTML, CSS and JavaScript source code to a "cloud compiler" that generates apps for every supported platform" - JS can execute in the cloud and will never be seen by browser. Not all JS is browser/client executed.